# RTX A5000 Dual Monitor on Z790 Taichi

Tags: nvidia, sound, multiple-monitors

I'm having five problems with a new build ubuntu 22.04 LTS. Nvidia RTX A5000, ASRock Z790 Taichi, BIOS 4.11, i9-13900K.

First of all, I had to manually load the WiFi drivers with
sudo apt install linux-modules-iwlwifi-generic
sudo reboot
Perhaps ubuntu should include generic drivers as a fall back.

Now, about the monitors.  Somewhat better monitor operation is reached by using pure DisplayPort connection.  A passive DP to HDMI cable usually doesn't work.  Like most DisplayPort these days, it handles HDMI as a native alternate mode. If it helps, Windows operation is flawless in this regard on this same bare metal.

Now the big problem is that dual monitor operation is very buggy.  The only way to achieve it is to cold boot with one monitor turned off and then turn the other monitor on after logging in.  Otherwise the screen goes blank and never recovers.  Even that procedure does not always work.  Also, it is not possible to reposition the monitors or to switch a monitor to a different input and then back.  Instant black screen with no recovery.  I've tried several of the drivers.  The Nouveau seems to be the most robust.  If a NVIDIA brand driver is used, the card isn't usually recognized on boot and I'm left with a single-monitor 600x800 machine.

The fourth problem is that I can't get sound.  Settings=>Sound shows the HDMI/DisplayPort 3 GA102 High Definition Audio Controller and Headphones - USB Audio if plugged in.  No sound from the monitor or headphone.

Another is that I can't get to console.  That is, ctrl + alt + F1 puts me to a blank screen that doesn't accept keystrokes.

I was a Linux user & contributor in the 1990s, I'm surprised to see this many hardware issues.

Help and suggestions are dearly appreciated.

--Mike

PS: It was a relief to see GNOME finally makes it easy to specify desktop link icons.  That is cool.

Comment: Do you have the proprietary Nvidia drivers installed and running? Even when installed you need to disable Secure Boot - you can unless dual-booting with Windows 11 - or use MOKutil to sign the drivers. A LOT has changed since the 90s, many or most things are way easier now but a couple of scenarios (e.g. UEFI with Secure Boot) are a little bit more involved.

Comment: The additional drivers are installed, but I'm using the Nouveau driver. I've done three clean installs of ubuntu 22.04 and if I check the Additional drivers box, I got a little farther.  It never ran the i9-13900k GPU right, so I donated my RTX A5000 to the cause and was finally able to get something other than 600x800.I did put Windows 11 Pro on a different M.2 SSD, installed 2nd. The ASRock AMI BIOS let's me pick which OS to launch.

Comment: So many things wrong in the previous comment I won't even bother. Suffice to say newer Nvidia cards DO NEED the Nvidia drivers installed AND running (users may need to disable Secure Boot in UEFI - the best choice if NOT dual-booting with Windows 11 - or manually sign the drivers with MOKutil).

Answer (score 0):

The comment from ChangnAuto about needing the Nvidia drivers is correct. I found from an nvidea forum that specifically the proprietary and NON open driver is needed. nvidia-driver-525(proprietary) seems to work. I had tried a few others, opting for tested or open kernel, but they do not work.

Sound is sort of fixed, too, in that settings->Sound Works put the pavucontrol does not work.

Thank-you.